# Spring JMS: replyQosSettings via XML Configuration

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-jms

I'm using Spring JMS 5.3.6 for an application where I need to set a TimeToLive for my response messages.
The application is configured via XML and is using the JMS namespace.

When reading the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.6/reference/html/integration.html#jms-namespace) my guess was that I need to create a `JmsListenerContainerFactory` instance which I then pass to the listener-container via the factory-id attribute.

But the documentation is not really clear here (or doesn't match the description). Because it states:

> You can automatically expose such settings as a JmsListenerContainerFactory by specifying the id of the bean to expose through the factory-id attribute, as the following example shows

But the following example then doesn't contain the factory-id attribute.

This is my current configuration:

```xml
  <bean id="replyQosSettings" class="org.springframework.jms.support.QosSettings">
    <constructor-arg name="deliveryMode" value="1"/>
    <constructor-arg name="priority" value="4"/>
    <constructor-arg name="timeToLive" value="300000"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jmsListenerContainerFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="replyQosSettings" ref="replyQosSettings"/>
  </bean>

  <jms:listener-container factory-id="jmsListenerContainerFactory">
    <jms:listener destination="starter.load" ref="starterJmsListener" method="startLoad" concurrency="3" selector="destinationServer = '${hub.name}' OR destinationServer IS NULL"/>
    <jms:listener destination="starter.isLoadRunning" ref="starterJmsListener" method="isRunning" selector="destinationServer = '${hub.name}' OR destinationServer IS NULL"/>
  </jms:listener-container>
```

But this doesn't work and after hours of debugging I've no idea how to get it working.

I also tried my own `MessageListenerContainer` implementation with hard-coded replyQosSettings but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the schema documentation for `listener-container`...

```
Each listener child element will be hosted by a container whose configuration
is determined by this parent element. This variant builds standard JMS
listener containers, operating against a specified JMS ConnectionFactory. When
a factory-id attribute is present, the configuration defined by this element is
exposed as a org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory. It is
therefore possible to only define this element without any child to just expose
a container factory.
```

and

```xml
        <xsd:attribute name="factory-id" type="xsd:string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
Expose the settings defined by this element as a org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory
so that they can be reused with other endpoints.
            ]]></xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
```

The `factory-id` is NOT a reference to a container factory, it turns the XML element into a container factory and it should not have any child elements.

The reply QOS is not supported by the jms xml namespace.

You need to define your listener container(s) as a `<bean />` <strike>and set its `replyQosSettings` property</strike>.

The `messageListener` should be a `MessageListenerAdapter` to wrap your listener bean, and set its `replyQosSettings` property.

Container factories are normally used for creating containers for methods annotated with `@JmsListener`.

Comment: Thx for your answer.
The only thing I have to add is that you have to set the responseQosSettings on the MessageListenerAdapter and not on the container.

Comment: Fixed. An alternative is to create a `BeanPostProcessor` and, for each container bean, call `getMessageListener()`, cast it to a `MessageListenerAdapter` and set the reply QOS there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gary Russel for the hints.
I think it's a little sad for spring that it has to get so verbose (espacially if you have a lot of listeners) just to get some Qol settings on the response messages.

But here it is:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
<property name="destination" ref="isLoadRunningQueue"/>
<property name="messageSelector" value="destinationServer = '${hub.name}' OR destinationServer IS NULL"/>
<property name="messageListener">
  <bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
    <property name="responseQosSettings" ref="replyQosSettings"/>
    <property name="defaultListenerMethod" value="isRunning"/>
    <property name="delegate" ref="starterJmsListener"/>
  </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: An alternative is to create a `BeanPostProcessor` and, for each container bean, call `getMessageListener()`, cast it to a `MessageListenerAdapter` and set the reply QOS there.